# Laravel 5.3 Добавить уникальную запись в БД

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel5

Хочу сделать так, чтобы запись в БД добавлялась только 1 раз пользователем, то есть нужно сделать проверку на наличие user_id, если этот пользователь ещё не добавлял ничего, то добавить, если уже добавлял то ничего не делать. Знаю что можно получить количество записей по user_id, но хотел сделать одним запросом.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'user_id' => 'required|unique:user_id',
    'text' => 'required',
]);

DB::table('suggestions')->insert([
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
    'text' => $request->input('advert'),
]);
```

Comment: То есть вы хотите объединить валидацию и инсерт в 1 запрос? Не могу понять в чём суть вопроса.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan, да.

Comment: Так зачем так делать? Не правильно всё тулить в 1 метод или 1 запрос, тем что вы уберёте один запрос на exist особо вам ничего не даст.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan то есть правильнее получить количество записей с БД, а потом по нему сделать проверку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понял вы не совсем поняли как работает правило [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique).

Вы просто создаете в валидаторе правило, которое посмотрит есть ли в таблице `suggestions` записи от пользователя `user_id` и выдаст ошибку если есть хоть одна запись. То есть вам ничего не нужно самому делать, написали валидатор:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'user_id' => 'required|unique:suggestions,user_id',
    'text' => 'required'
]);
```

Всё что после валидатора будет выполнятся только в случае если данные его прошли, то есть в вашем случае записей от пользователя нет и можно их записывать, что вы и делали:

```
DB::table('suggestions')->insert([
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
    'text' => $request->input('advert'),
]);
```

В вашем случае в в правиле не указали таблицу и валидатор вообще не должен был работать или искать запись в таблице `user_id`.

Только ещё одна штука, вы в валидаторе проверяете поле `text`, а в базу записываете `advert`, лучше бы в базу писать данные в которых уверенны и которые прошли валидацию.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал как правильно сделать проверку, а там точно кома а не точка в `suggestions,user_id`?

Comment: @Abmin точно запятая